# Services with google fused location API

Tags: android

I get an error when I have a service which runs in background/after apps gets killed.But doesnot work in OPPO, VIVO, MIUI devices.Tried Wake up locks,onTaskRemoved .Done all setting Autostart,Battery,Security, etc.

```
public class MyService extends Service implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();
    GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    private PowerManager mPowerManager;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
    public Location location;
    public static final long INTERVAL = 20000;//variable to execute services every 10 second
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(); // run on another Thread to avoid crash
    private Timer mTimer = null; // timer handling


    public static final String ACTION_LOCATION_BROADCAST = MyService.class.getName() + "LocationBroadcast";
    public static final String EXTRA_LATITUDE = "extra_latitude";
    public static final String EXTRA_LONGITUDE = "extra_longitude";
    DataBaseHandler dataBaseHandler;
    private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Notification myNotification;
    public static Location mCurrentLocation, lStart, lEnd;
    double speed;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // cancel if service is  already existed

        if (mTimer != null)
            mTimer.cancel();
        else
            mTimer = new Timer(); // recreate new timer
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, INTERVAL);// schedule task

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        dataBaseHandler = new DataBaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(9);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(2000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        // onTaskRemoved(intent);



        int priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY; //by default
        //PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY, PRIORITY_LOW_POWER, PRIORITY_NO_POWER are the other priority modes


        mLocationRequest.setPriority(priority);
        mLocationClient.connect();

        //Make it stick to the notification panel so it is less prone to get cancelled by the Operating System.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

 @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * LOCATION CALLBACKS
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

            Log.d(TAG, "== Error On onConnected() Permission not granted");
            //Permission not granted by user so cancel the further execution.

            return;
        }
        try {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected to Google API");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the connection to the
     * location client drops because of an error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    }

    //to get the location change
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Location changed");
        if (location != null) {
            this.location = location;
            mCurrentLocation = location;
            if (lStart == null) {
                lStart = mCurrentLocation;
                lEnd = mCurrentLocation;
            } else {
                lEnd = mCurrentLocation;
            }

            updateUI(location);
            Preferences.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setLatitude(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            Preferences.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setLongitude(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
            Log.d(TAG, "== location != null");
            String lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            String lng = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            if (FlightModeReceiver.isFlight()) {
                return;
            }
            if (!GpsReceiver.isGps(this)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        if (Preferences.getInstance(this).getService().equals("1")) {
            showNotification();
        }

    }

 public String CompareTime(String strTimeToCompare)

    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int dtHour;
        int dtMin;
        int iAMPM;
        String strAMorPM = null;
        Date dtCurrentDate;

        try {
            Date TimeToCompare = sdf.parse(strTimeToCompare);
            dtMin = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            dtHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            iAMPM = cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
            if (iAMPM == 1)

            {
                strAMorPM = "pm";

            }
            if (iAMPM == 0)

            {
                strAMorPM = "am";

            }

            dtCurrentDate = sdf.parse(dtHour + ":" + dtMin + " " + strAMorPM);
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(dtCurrentDate),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(TimeToCompare),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (dtCurrentDate.after(TimeToCompare))

            {

                return "1";

            }

            if (dtCurrentDate.before(TimeToCompare))

            {
                return "2";

            }
            if (dtCurrentDate.equals(TimeToCompare))

            {
                return "3";

            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return "4";

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to connect to Google API");

    }

  private void updateUI(Location location) {
        speed = location.getSpeed() * 18 / 5;
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(lStart.distanceTo(lEnd)-lEnd.getAccuracy()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (lStart.distanceTo(lEnd)-lEnd.getAccuracy()>0&&lStart.distanceTo(lEnd)>9) {
            Preferences.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setDistance(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(Preferences.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getDistance()) + (lStart.distanceTo(lEnd) / 1000.00)));
            Main2Activity.endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                Main2Activity.tempDist.setText(new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(Double.valueOf(Preferences.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getDistance())) + " Km.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            lStart = lEnd;
            Main2Activity.startTime = Main2Activity.endTime;
        }
    }

 private void showNotification() {
        try {

            myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("mTrack")
                    .setContentText(String.valueOf(new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(Double.valueOf(Preferences.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getDistance())) + " Km."))
                    .setTicker("Notification!")
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    //  .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mtrack_icon)
                    .build();

            myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[TO BE STUDIED](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground)

To run a service when the app is in the background you need to specify that the service should stay in the foreground:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)          
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("channel", "MyName", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.setDescription("a description")
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);               
}

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

Notification notification =
          new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel")
    .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.notification_title))
    .setContentText(getText(R.string.notification_message))
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setTicker(getText(R.string.ticker_text))
    .build();

yourService.startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

as the documentation states:

> Note: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, the system imposes
>   restrictions on running background services when the app itself isn't
>   in the foreground. In most cases like this, your app should use a
>   scheduled job instead.

I don't know whether the note above applies to your use case